# Excel/LibreOffice Calc - Setting a value dependent on another value as that second value rises at a uniform rate

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Essentially the value in C24 is dependent on the value in C18.

The value in C24 should be 33 if the value in C18 is **2230 or less**.

The value in C24 should be 39.5 if the value in C18 is **2950 exactly**.

The value in C24 should be 40.8 if the value in C18 is **3100 exactly**.

The value in C24 rises at a uniform rate as the value in C18 increases (from 2230 -> 2950 -> 3100). Imagine this as if it were on a graph and a straight line was drawn for these 3 values. Specifically imagine if C24's value was X and C18's value was Y. It's a straight line drawn so I'd like the formula to figure out X (C24's value in this case) based on the Y-point (C18's value)

So in the case from 2230 to 2950 the difference is 720. From what I've calculated the value in C24 goes up incrementally by .00903 as the value in C18 rises incrementally by 1 until it reaches 2950. Then the value goes up incrementally by .00867. These values are rounded. It would be ideal if excel will do this calculation on its own (i.e. the formula shouldn't stipulate that the value goes up by 0.00903 instead it'll know what the value in C24 should be based on the value in C18 as it rises at a uniform rate (i.e. a straight line on a graph)).

Ultimately all final values on the sheet will be rounded up to the hundredth.

I appreciate any assistance on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: This may not be useful since your data isn't exactly linear, or, you may need to use it twice (for the different slopes), but for what it's worth: In Excel365, the LINEST function accepts 2 or more Pairs of x and y values, and outputs information including the slope, y intercept and "accuracy of fit" (which will be 100% if it's perfectly a straight line), and more. This is useful for exploring your data, But, TREND actually uses this info (without showing it) to interpolate an unknown y from any x (from memory, only within the known range. Use FORECAST to extrapolate outside, I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not really the straight line between the three points as stated before contradicting, you need a slightly different approach than just a simple linear calculation.

So:

```
=IF(C18<2230,  "You didn't specify what happens if C18<2230.",  IF(C18<=2950,  33+(6.5*(C18-2230)/(2950-2230)),  IF(C18<=3100,  33+6.5+(1.3*(C18-2950)/(3100-2950)),  "You didn't specify what happens if C18>3100.")))
```

You did not specify what is to happen if C18 is outside of the range, low or high, hence the first and last conditions.

Then using the `IF`, just deal with each of the pieces that actually are straight lines using a simple "base value plus the full rise for the portion times a ratio of how far through the portion it is" (so a standard "base value plus an interpolated value" approach). Since I've started with the "below the first value you specify" possibility, I went "up" through the range, dealing with below the low value, the lower range, the higher range, and finally the above the high value. You could just as easily go the opposite direction, if that "feels" more "right" to you or some outside reason makes it worthwhile.

However, jumping about (say... higher than either straight line piece, then the low range line, then the below all part, then the high range line) would require a very carefully considered and written formula. And why would anyone want that?

I've written out all the pieces in the formula in case you want to easily change "hard coded" values, like the "2950" to cells that contain the values so that they would be easy to change. If preferred, you needn't, and then could, for example, calculate (2950-2230) and put in 720 instead of the (2950-2230).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Values below 2230 or above 3100 are invalid. To help it make more sense, 2230, 2950, and 3100 are weight tier values. Another value is assigned to each of those 3 numbers and they go from a straight line to 2230 to 2950 and then 2950 to 3100.